# Include functions of different files in Node.js

Tags: node.js, include

Okay, so... I load several files from a folder and want the functions from the loaded files to be loaded into the file that loads the files. As if they had been in the file from the start.

My current code works fine so far, but I can't use "this" in the loaded function, because it's not the "this" from the file that loaded the function.

Loading all files and include their functions.

```
return fs.readdirAsync(path.join(__dirname, 'Handlers')).map(file => {
    if (file.substr(file.length - 3) === '.js') {
        let handlerFile = require(path.join(__dirname, 'Handlers', file))

        for (const handlerName of Object.keys(handlerFile)) {
            this[handlerName] = handlerFile[handlerName]
        }
    }
})
```

This is how the loaded file looks like:

```
module.exports = {

    test: (arguments) => {
        console.log(this)
    }

}
```

So, if I call this.test() now in the file that loaded the function, *console.log(this)* is executed. Everything works so far, but "this" is empty.

Is there a way that the loaded function gets the "this" from the file that loads the functions? (Without passing it to the function)

I hope you understand what I want. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly do you want `this` to be in your `test()` method?  Your use of the arrow function sets `this` to be what `this` would be in the module as the module loads (the lexical `this` when your method is defined) which is not your object.  It's probably the module object itself - I haven't actually checked what the value of `this` in during module initialization.

Comment: @jfriend00 I want `this` to be the one of the module that has loaded the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `this` is not automatically passed from your original environment to the loaded module.  When a module is loaded with `require()`, the value of `this` in that module is set to the value of `module.exports` and since your `test()` method is declared using an arrow function, the value of this inside of your `.test()` method will be the lexical value of `this` which in the case of the code you show me will be the original value of `module.exports` (before you reassigned it) since that's what `this` was when the module was originally loaded.

If you're calling the `.test()` method with something like `this.test()`, then a very simple fix is to just stop using an arrow function for your method and use a regular function.  Regular functions called as methods as in `obj.test()` will set the value of `this` to be `obj` in the method.  If that's what you want, then just stop using an arrow function.  In fact, there are very, very, very few cases where you want a method to be declared using an arrow function.  Methods should nearly always be normal function definitions.  Remember, an arrow function is NOT just a shortcut syntax.  It changes the behavior for setting the value of `this`.

So, you could just change your loaded file to this:

```
module.exports = {

    test: function(args) {
        console.log(this)
    }

}
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks for your help! :)